# CakePHP Sending data from view to controller via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, view, controller

I'm new to cakephp. I'm trying to make a simple ajax request that would modify a part of the screen. I've found several examples on the web, but I can't mix them together!
When I click the button **btnNewPhon**, I want to send the content of the input **txtPhon** to be sent to the controller adminController. Then in the view, the div **dataToShow** would be updated to show the data sent by the controller.

I'm almost there, but I don't know how to send the content of the inputs **phonID** and **phonTxt** to the controller and I don't know how to get the data in the controller. Here's my code.

View **index.ctp**:

```
<div id="dataToshow"></div>
<input id="phonID" type="text">
<input id="phonTxt" type="text">
<button id="btnNewPhon">New</button>
```

Ajax view **ajax_response.ctp**:

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

Javascript **admin.js** (included in the view):

```
$(function() {
  $('#btnNewPhon').click(function() {
    a = $("#txtPhon").val ;
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      datatype:'json',
      cache: false,
      data: <<< I don't know what to put here >>>,
      url:"admin/addPhon",
      update:"#dataToshow"
    });
  });
});
```

Controller **adminController.php**:

```
public function addPhon() {

     if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        // Treatment of the new data here

        //create current date in chosen format
        $new_data = '##'.$this->request->param('phonID').'-'.$this->request->param('phonTxt').'##';

        //set current date as content to show in view
        $this->set('content', $new_data); 

        //render spacial view for ajax
        $this->render('ajax_response', 'ajax');

     }
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: You should also consider using the proper extension: `url:"admin/addPhon.json"

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

1) In the view, I need to add a form around the fields and to set a **name** attribute to them, like:

```
<form id="goNewPhon">              
    <input id="phonID" name="phonID" type="text">
    <input id="phonTxt" name="phonTxt" type="text">
</form>
```

2) In the js, I serialize the form:

```
data: $("#goNewPhon").serialize(),
```

3) In the controller, I use **data** to get the passed parameters:

```
$this->request->data['phonTxt']
```

Now I works.

Comment: It would be better to use the CakePHP internal FormHelper to generate forms. Then you wouldn't have run into this problem in the first place :)