# CakePHP AJAX Response from Controller to View

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

We are using an old version of CakePHP for our App API and backend.  I have created a new view page and am trying to call a controller to do work and return something to the view.

I have followed the post here: [CakePHP Sending data from view to controller via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315822/cakephp-sending-data-from-view-to-controller-via-ajax)

and added in some code into the controller to show that it is indeed getting there, which it is (I get the message and ID in the debug.log):

```
$parentID = $this->request->data['id'];
CakeLog::write(LOG_DEBUG, "Parent ID is ".$parentID);
```

But nothing gets back to my view.  How can I start to debug this?  I do not understand how the ajax_response gets back to my div #dataToshow?

Here are my files:

**View (parent.ctp):**

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#btnCreatePDF').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      datatype:'json',
      cache: false,
      data: $("#parentSubmissionDetails").serialize(),
      url:"/v2.0/api/parentSubmission2PDF",
      update:"#dataToshow"
    });
  });
});
</script>

<div id="dataToshow"></div>
<form id="parentSubmissionDetails">              
    <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $parent['ParentData']['id']; ?>">
</form>
<button id="btnCreatePDF">Do something with AJAX</button>
```

**Controller function (parentSubmission2PDF):**

```
public function parentSubmission2PDF() 
    {
        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            // Treatment of the new data here
    
            //get the parent submission id
            $parentID = $this->request->data['id'];
            CakeLog::write(LOG_DEBUG, "Parent ID is ".$parentID);
    
            //set current date as content to show in view
            $this->set('content', $parentID); 
    
            //render spacial view for ajax
            $this->render('/Api/ajax_response', 'ajax');
    
         }
    }
```

**Ajax Response View (ajax_response.ctp):**

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

Comment: If you look at the details of the request in your browser's developer tools, what does it show as the response headers and data?

Comment: For a POST request, you have to send the csrfToken sent by the backend. In the header of the POST request add something like : headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                'X-CSRF-Token': csrftoken,
            }

Comment: got it working by just doing an
`echo $responsevalue; exit();`
This sent the $responsevalue back to my view in:
`success: function (response)`